# Machine Learning Implementation when dealing with high variance data

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm am trying to classify MLB (Baseball) games whose score go over the total based on the total and the number of people who have bet the over. The total is a number set by Vegas and a bettor can either bet the over - meaning both team's combined scores will be greater than the number Vegas set or you can bet the under mean both team's combined scores will be less than the number set by Vegas. The training data coming in is stored in a CSV file a looks like this `Team` `Total` `Over_Perc` `Cover` i.e. `NYY` `8.5` `0.61` `0`. I've tested several different models and the highest accuracy achieved was using the `RandomForestClassifier`. I would like to know if I am implementing this model correctly and if there is anything I can do to tune the parameters to achieve better accuracy?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import metrics

training_data = pd.read_csv('/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/ML/Data/Training_Data/Training_Data_Total.csv')
df_model = training_data.copy()
scaler = StandardScaler()

features = [['Total', 'Over_Perc' ]]
for feature in features:
    df_model[feature] = scaler.fit_transform(df_model[feature])

test_data = pd.read_csv('/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/ML/Data/Test_Data/Test_Data_Total.csv')
X = training_data.iloc[:,1:3]  #independent columns
y = training_data.iloc[:,-1]   #target column 

results = []

# fit final model
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, random_state=42) # 0.54

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

print("Accuracy:", round(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred),2))

# define one new data instance

index = 0
count = 0

while count < len(test_data):
    team = test_data.loc[index].at['Team']
    total = test_data.loc[index].at['Total']
    over_perc = test_data.loc[index].at['Over_Perc']

    Xnew = [[ total, over_perc ]]
    # make a prediction
    ynew = model.predict_proba(Xnew)
    # show the inputs and predicted outputs
    results.append(
        {
            'Team': team,
            'Cover': round(ynew[0][1],2)
        })
    index += 1
    count += 1
    
sorted_results = sorted(results, key=lambda k: k['Cover'], reverse=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_results, columns=[
    'Team', 'Cover'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/ML/Results/Over_Probability.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') # pylint: disable=abstract-class-instantiated
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
writer.save()
```

Comment: It would be optimal to link the training files (or some "fake" ones with the same format if you do not want to share the originals) to let reviewers test your code

Comment: @Caridorc sure here's a link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qxuOkUPeR5qIscmiVg9KRXm9i6mdIPbcNWjQtCCAx4c/edit?usp=sharing